# Proving that integral of big oh is not following normal polynomial integral.

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

I want to prove that \begin{align}
 \int_0^x O(t^n)dt  \neq O(x^{n+1}) 
\end{align}
At first I tried to partially integrate but it did not work.

Thanks,

Axel

Comment: I don't understand exactly what the integral means.  $O(t^n)$ is not a function, but a class of functions.  Can you explain?

Comment: My apologies for the last comment, I overlooked something

Comment: @saulspatz does it make more sense if the integrand is a(x)*x^n instead, where a(x) is limited function when close to 0?

Comment: If you want the integrand to be $O(n)$ then you would need $|a(x)|<C$ for $x>K$ for some positive constants $C$ and $K$.  The behavior near $0$ doesn't affect that, but of course the integral needn't even converge.  If $a$ is bounded, then the integral *is* $O(x^{n+1})$.  For example, $\frac1x$ is $O(x^n)$ as $x\to\infty$ for any positive integer $n$.